# I need help for my sign up form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I was doing doing a sign up form and it not includes back-end part. I almost done but right now ı have a problem within javascript part with Email confirmation thing. It's a simple thing, since ı will leave codes down here you will also see it. I've tryed something and still didn't deleted them. When you see those codes probably undurstand my problem. plesase help me with this

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const Name = document.querySelector("#Name");
const Email = document.querySelector("#Email");
const Password = document.querySelector("#password");
const Password__Confirm = document.querySelector("#password-confirm");
const Submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
const bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
const Notice = document.querySelectorAll(".notice");
const notice_1 = document.querySelector("#notice--1");
const notice_2 = document.querySelector("#notice--2");
const notice_3 = document.querySelector("#notice--3");

Submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
  const nameLength = Name.value.length;
  console.log(Email.value.split("@"));
  const emailValue = Email.value.trim();
  const [firstPart, email] = Email.value.split("@");
  console.log(email);
  const password = Password.value;
  console.log(password);
  const password_c = Password__Confirm.value;
  console.log(nameLength);
  Notice.forEach((notice) => {
    notice.classList.add("hidden");

    if (nameLength <= 1) {
      notice_1.classList.remove("hidden");
      console.log(Name.value);
      //console.log(password);
    }
    //if (!(emailValue.includes("@"))) {
    //  nostice_2.classList.remove(".hidden");
    //}
    //if (!(email.includes("gmail.com")) ||
    //    !(email.includes("hotmail.com"))) {
    //  notice_2.classList.remove("hidden");
    //}
    if (password.length < 6 || !(password===password_c)) {
      notice_3.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
}
.container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 40%;
    top: 30%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 50px;
}
.notice{
    color: red;
}
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Confirmation</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="">
            <label for="">Name</label><br>
            <input class="bar" id="Name" type="text"><br>
            <label for="">Email</label><br>
            <input class="bar" id="Email" type="text"><br>
            <label for="">Password</label><br>
            <input class="bar" id="password" type="password"><br>
            <label for="">Confirm Password</label><br>
            <input class="bar" id="password-confirm" type="password"><br>
            <input class="submit" type="button" value="Sing Up">
        </form>
        <ul class="warning">
            <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--1">Name is required</li>
            <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--2">Email is invalid</li>
            <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--3">Password must be 6 character or more</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You looped through Notices, but added back `.hidden` to the notices. I made minor changes to your code. You will probably understand it when you see the code. Also, your variable `notice_2` was misspelled.

```js
const Name = document.querySelector("#Name");
const Email = document.querySelector("#Email");
const Password = document.querySelector("#password");
const Password__Confirm = document.querySelector("#password-confirm");
const Submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
const Notice = document.querySelectorAll(".notice");

Submit.addEventListener("click", () => {

  const nameLength = Name.value.length;
  const emailValue = Email.value.trim();
  const [firstPart, email] = Email.value.split("@");
  const password = Password.value;
  const password_c = Password__Confirm.value;
  
  Notice.forEach((notice) => {
    notice.classList.add("hidden");

    if (notice.id == 'notice--1' && nameLength <= 1) {
      notice.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else if (notice.id == 'notice--2') {
      if (!(emailValue.includes("@"))) {
        notice.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
    }
    else if (notice.id == 'notice--3' && (password.length < 6 || !(password === password_c))) {
      notice.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.notice {
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <label for="">Name</label><br>
    <input class="bar" id="Name" type="text"><br>
    <label for="">Email</label><br>
    <input class="bar" id="Email" type="text"><br>
    <label for="">Password</label><br>
    <input class="bar" id="password" type="password"><br>
    <label for="">Confirm Password</label><br>
    <input class="bar" id="password-confirm" type="password"><br>
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
  <ul class="warning">
    <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--1">Name is required</li>
    <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--2">Email is invalid</li>
    <li class="notice hidden" id="notice--3">Password must be 6 character or more</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```